# VPN issue on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn

- I have a windows 7 64bit machine. I am connecting via wifi
- When i enter a new VPN profile i and try and connect i an 868 error
- however if i open a profile that was created a few months ago and edit the username and password to the new account i can connect
- i have compared every setting in the old and new they appear to be the same

Any thoughts?

Any recommendations on an alternate vpn client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember right, 868 error means the server cannot be contact/resolved. are you sure you can telnet to the server on 1723? (providing it's PPTP)

My answer is check to make sure you can contact the server that your trying to VPN to with both ping and telnet.

Comment: yeah, i can telnet and it is pptp. The key issue is that the old profiles work and the new ones don't

Comment: When you say profile do you mean a new connection to a different server/customer? or do you mean a new windows profile setting up exisiting vpns?

Comment: Hi James, you know in windows 7 & vista your vpn connections can be access via "connect to a network". So if i use an existing profile in there it works. But your raise an interesting questions. Can i connection using a difference windows profile. I'll give that a go.

Comment: ok, so i tried a new windows profile but not luck. Obviously i've installed something that has changed a windows setting. any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure if this helps. When i tried to connect to VPN it saids "Connecting via WAN Miniport SSTP

Comment: to be clear, i've change "Type of VPN" to automatic. I have tried setting it to PPTP ( which is what my hosting company accepts )

Comment: Check this out it may help - sorry for the late reply. - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/5a06f0e0-84b9-4c05-8dc0-1305a7c66c69